# JS: How to count all values in nested array

Tags: javascript

I'm using a nested array like this:

```
const data = [
  [0],
  [2],
  [[1], 3]
  1
]
```

Is it possible to count all values together. In this example the result should be 7 (0+2+1+3+1).
And is it also possible to count how many arrays are used? This would be 5 arrays

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 const sumUp = array => array.reduce((sum, el) => sum + (Array.isArray(el) ? sumUp(el) : +el), 0);
```

This uses a recursive approach with reduce.

Comment: Is it possible to count also the arrays?

Comment: Yes it is. May try that yourself? ;)